# SQL concat first before order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

We know that ordering the query can slow down the process specially if the number of rows are too large. If we're about to order the query by more than one field, the process will be much slower.

```
ORDER by field1, field2, field3
```

I am thinking that concatenating those fields first then use that in the order will help.

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1, field2, field3) AS useForOrder FROM table ORDER BY useForOrder
```

Am I right? Does using that technique is effective?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: It also depends on the index. If those 3 columns are indexes, specifying invidualy wins.

Comment: @Phil, I experienced a huge table rows before and I don't have an access for that now. So now I am working with new table with small rows as of today but in the future the rows will get numbered.

Comment: @IvorySantos Use an *explain plan* to determine the query's efficiency, not execution time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you get this idea:  "If we're about to order the query by more than one field, the process will be much slower."

The `order by` clause in a query requires sorting the data.  Sorting the data is going to take about the same amount of time, regardless of the size of the key, because sorting algorithms require reading and writing the data multiple times.

You may be confused by that fact that -- sometimes -- an actual sort isn't necessary because there is an available index with the right ordering.  However, this has nothing to do with the number of columns, because a composite index can match multiple columns in the `order by`.

Concatenating the results in the `select` is going to have minimal effect on the sort performance.  It might have an effect on the sort order, however.  Consider what happens with the following values:

- 'Cat', '', 'Luna'
- 'Catalog', '', ''
- 'Cat', 'Woman', ''
- 'Catwalk', '', ''

By concatenation, these would sort as:

- Catalog
- Catluna
- Catwalk
- Catwoman

By field, these would be:

- Cat Luna
- Cat Woman
- Catalog
- Catwalk

The order is not the same.

Comment: Base on my experienced, ordering huge content slower the process.

Comment: @IvorySantos . . . `order by` performance is more likely to be affected by what is in the `select` clause than what is in the `order by` clause (actually, both sets of columns/expressions need to be in the data being sorted but `select` typically has more data).